# Field extensions and monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $[E_1:F]=m<\infty$ and $E_1$ is algebraic extension of $F$. If $K$ is any extension of $F$ then the number of monomorphism of $E_1/F$ into $K/F$ is at most $m$.

I am trying to prove this by induction on $[E_1:F]$. If I pick an irreducible polynomial $g(x)$ with degree $m$ over $F$ and look at the solutions for $g(x)$ in $E_1$, I can construct a sort of intermediate field between $E_1$ and the field generated by adjoining the root of $g(x)$ to $F$. However how do I translate this information and know something about $K$ as it can bigger or smaller field?

Comment: The problem when using induction on $[E_1:F]$, is that even when $[E_1:F]$ is large (for example a large prime) there might not be any intermediate fields to use the induction hypothesis on.
Nevertheless, you could still use induction on $n$ where $E_1 = F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for some algebraic elements $x_1,\dots,x_n \in E_1$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: Since $K$ is any extension (and not a splitting field), how can I find an intermediate field which is a splitting field between $K$ and $F$?

Comment: Why do you think that you need such a splitting field?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: If I consider a map from $f: F\rightarrow F$ and consider the splitting field $F[x_1]$ of a polynomial $f(x)$, I can extend $f$ to a monomorphism between $F[x_1]$ and $K$ only if $f(x)$ has a solution in $K[x]$

Comment: Note that you only want to have an upper bound for the number of monomorphisms. It can happen that there are none at all. Moreover, note that what you stated is not only true for splitting fields of polynomials. If you adjoin an element $x_1 \in E_1$ to $F$, then a monomorphism $F[x_1]/F \rightarrow K/F$  is uniquely determined by a root in $K$ of the minimal polynomial of $x_1$ over $F$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is perhaps the induction proof you had in mind.

First, if $E=F$, the proposition is trivial.  Now suppose that we have proved the proposition for every subfield $F \subseteq E' \subsetneq E$.  Taking $E'$ to be maximal, and $a\in E\setminus E'$, we have $E = E'[a]$.  Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $E'$.

Now we count $F$-morphisms $E=E'[a]\to K$.  By the inductive hypothesis, there are at most $[E':F]$ $F$-morphisms $E'\to K$.  If $\varphi: E\to K$ is an $F$-morphism, then $a$ must be mapped to a root of $\varphi(f)$, a polynomial with at most $[E:E']$ roots.

Since $\varphi$ is determined by what it does to $E'$ and what it does to $a$, it follows that there are at most $[E':F][E:E']=[E:F]$ morphisms $E\to K$ that fix $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that E is a splitting field over F of some polynomial in F[x] using the fact that [E:F] is finite. Then m is the maximum number of automorphisms of E/F. If K/F contains no monomorphic images of E/F we are done. Otherwise any two monomorphic images of E in K/F are isomorphic. So we can regard all the monomorphic images as being a single subset of K. If z is one of the monomorphisms let it correspond to the identity automorphism. If w is another monomorphism let it correspond to the automorphism (z^-1)w. We are done.

Comment: I withdraw this solution because I do not believe one may assume all monomorphic images of E to each be the same subset of K.