# Why is there a "maximal" intermediate field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

It seems from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1785416/360858) that the following is true (possibly without the finiteness assumption, I have no idea):

> If $E/F$ is a finite field extension, then there exists a maximal intermediate field $E'$.

Presumably this means that $E'$ is an intermediate field and if $K$ is an intermediate field and $E' \subset K$, then $K = E$ (am I right?)

How to prove this?

Comment: For the finite situation, you can consider embedding the finite extension into a finite Galois extension. By Galois Theory, there are finite intermediate fields, including those which are subfields of the original finite extension. Getting rid of the finiteness condition, I have not found any counter examples yet but I could not think about a proof.

Comment: You might also use some knowledge in infinite Galois theory to work on it, in my view. I'm not very sure.

Comment: Presumably you mean to require $E\neq F$ and by "intermediate field" you mean $E'$ such that $F\subseteq E'\subset E$.

Comment: It is not necesseraly unique, see $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ having $3$ maximal subfields : $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$. You should show that $K$ is a maximal subfield of $E$ iff $[E:K]$ is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is:

> Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension such that $E\neq F$.  Then there is a field $E'$ such that $F\subseteq E'\subset E$ and there is no field $K$ such that $E'\subset K\subset E$.

To prove it, consider the set $S$ of all degrees $[E':F]$ of intermediate fields $E'\subset E$.  Then $S$ is a nonempty set of natural numbers, all of which are less than $[E:F]$.  Let $n$ be the greatest element of $S$, and choose $E'\subset E$ such that $[E':F]=n$.  Then if $E'\subset K\subset E$ we would have $$[K:F]=[K:E'][E':F]>[E':F]=n,$$ which is a contradiction since $n$ is the greatest element of $S$.

Comment: Thank you. Though, I don't see how your statement is any different than mine. Could you please point out the difference?

Comment: The assumption that $E\neq F$, and the requirement that $E'\neq E$.